# Determining research approach (deduction/induction) of a two-fold thesis project

Tags: research-process, thesis, methodology, qualitative-research

Background:
For our master thesis, we are exploring challenges with cross-border energy projects in the North Sea (wind farms, energy islands etc.) and how agile methodologies (usually used in private sector) can be implemented in the public sector to overcome these challenges.

1. We have a theoretical framework based on agile methodologies in the private sector and the limited literature on their implementation in the public sector
2. We have collected data from interview/reports to identify the challenges with cross-border energy projects
3. Our aim is to connect the above section together and provide recommendations for applying agile methodologies to solve the specific challenges

Our challenge:
Our research paper is motivated by agile methodologies to provide recommendations to solve challenges on cross-border projects - this is a deductive approach. However, data collection and analysis is very inductive, in that it is not based on theory and agile was not considered when identifying themes for analysis - this seems much more inductive. At the end, we wish to connect the analysed themes with agile and discuss how it can be applied to solve challenges.

Main question: Is this research project informed by a deductive approach, or both deductive/inductive, seeing as the data collection was not performed to "test" the theory or a hypothesis? Is it both and can it be both?

I am currently writing the methodological section and therefore wish to understand the premise for our two-fold research paper.